# EntityFramework Core one-to-many configuration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to configurate entity relation one-to-many.

Whats the way to configure to not allow to delete parent if it has childs and be allowed to creat parent without child?

Folling the EF Core documentation example. How can I configure Blog not allow to delete if it has Post but can creat blog withou post.

Comment: That's about validation. EF won't stop you from trying to delete a parent with children. We can only help you if you show what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set OnDelete Restrict in OnModelCreating method of your DbContext. as following:

Entities:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id{get; set;}

    public string Name{get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts{get; set;}
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id{get; set;}

    public string Name{get; set;}

    public int BlogId {get; set;}

    public virtual Blog Blog{get; set;}
}
```

Configuration in DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasMany(a => a.Posts)
        .WithOne(a => a.Blog)
        .HasForeignKey(a => a.BlogId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
}
```